# File browser of ckeditor increase overhead by loading unnecessary folders

Tags: files, wysiwyg

When I try to use the image file browser of the CKeditor, the browser takes a lot of time to load. When I checked the request, I found that the browser loads a lot of folders that are not even displayed.

The logs shows that the file browser try to load all the folders under `/pub/sites/default/files/` will it be possible to limit that to only request the folders under `/pub/sites/default/files/u285430` where u285430 is the user folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help people having the same issue.

The way IMCE works will scan the whole directory over Http requests then filter using permissions. This can cause a big overhead.

My solution was to dynamically generate new folder every month, this way I make sure that there are not that many pictures to load every time.